# через scrapy не могу распарсить iframe

Tags: python, iframe, scrapy

Сайт, который разбираю http://catalogue.ufi.it/menu/menu.php?lingua=en. Там фрейм для верхней части документа где находятся selects с параметрами для поиска. В этот фрейм я попал через "src" iframe(POST), категории для поиска я выкачал, теперь пытаюсь отправлять POST запрос, который уходит при нажатии на кнопку "Поиск", а точнее их в закладке инспектора браузера "сеть" - 2. На сайте после клика на кнопку, инфо подгружается в нижнюю половину окна - еще один фрейм, но без "src", как попасть в этот iframe, чтобы спарсить инфо? Первый POST - запрос получаю, тоже что и браузер

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2476575-52']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">parent.NM_apaga_erro()</script><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>List - </TITLE>
 <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <META http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT"/>
 <META http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="Mon, 18 Jun 2018 23:23:51 GMT"/>
 <META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"/>
 <META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="post-check=0, pre-check=0"/>
 <META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
</HEAD>
<BODY class="scGridPage">
<FORM style="display:none;" name="form_ok" method="POST" action="grid_1.php" target="_self">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="script_case_init" value="1"> 
<INPUT type="hidden" name="script_case_session" value="p1r44ove2rqodcpfl2a7lliqc5"> 
<INPUT type="hidden" name="nmgp_opcao" value="pesq"> 
</FORM>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
 document.form_ok.submit();
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

А вот после второго запроса, хотя его может и не стоит делать и response должен вернуть код внутреннего фрейма автоматически, получаю много HTML с развернутыми селектами и ошибку:

```
<iframe id="nmsc_iframe_grid_1" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" topmargin="0px" leftmargin="0px" align="center" height="770px" name="nm_iframe_grid_1" scrolling="auto" src="grid_1.php?nmgp_opcao=pesq&script_case_init=1&script_case_session=d6n7n12rsabuoq32bqjf62pkg6" width="100%"></iframe>\r\n</td></tr></table></td></tr>\r\n</TABLE>\r\n   <INPUT type="hidden" name="form_condicao" value="3">\r\n</FORM> \r\n   <FORM style="display:none;" name="form_cancel"  method="POST" action="" target="_self"> \r\n   <INPUT type="hidden" name="script_case_init" value="1"> \r\n   <INPUT type="hidden" name="script_case_session" value="d6n7n12rsabuoq32bqjf62pkg6"> \r\n   <INPUT type="hidden" name="nmgp_opcao" value="resumo"> \r\n   </FORM> \r\n<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">\r\n function nm_submit_form()\r\n {\r\n    document.F1.target = "nm_iframe_grid_1";\r\n    document.F1.submit();\r\n }\r\n function limpa_form()\r\n {\r\n   document.F1.reset();\r\n   NM_apaga_erro();\r\n   document.F1.catalogo.value = "";\r\n   while (1 < document.F1.marcamod.length)\r\n   {\r\n       NM_length = document.F1.marcamod.length - 1;\r\n       document.F1.marcamod.options[NM_length] = null;\r\n   }\r\n   while (1 < document.F1.modello_idmodello.length)\r\n   {\r\n       NM_length = document.F1.modello_idmodello.length - 1;\r\n       document.F1.modello_idmodello.options[NM_length] = null;\r\n   }\r\n   while (1 < document.F1.versione_idversione.length)\r\n   {\r\n       NM_length = document.F1.versione_idversione.length - 1;\r\n       document.F1.versione_idversione.options[NM_length] = null;\r\n   }\r\n }\r\nfunction nm_tabula(obj, tam, cond)\r\n{\r\n   if (obj.value.length == tam)\r\n   {\r\n       for (i=0; i < document.F1.elements.length;i++)\r\n       {\r\n            if (document.F1.elements[i].name == obj.name)\r\n            {\r\n                i++;\r\n                campo = document.F1.elements[i].name;\r\n                campo2 = campo.lastIndexOf(\'_input_2\');\r\n                if (document.F1.elements[i].type == \'text\' && (campo2 == -1 || cond == \'bw\'))\r\n                {\r\n                    eval(\'document.F1.\' + campo + \'.focus()\');\r\n                }\r\n                break;\r\n            }\r\n       }\r\n   }\r\n}\r\n function SC_carga_evt_jquery()\r\n {\r\n }\r\n</SCRIPT>\r\n</BODY>\r\n</HTML>\r\n' is not JSON serializable
```

Есть у кого то мысли как получить инфо из этого фрейма? Я так понимаю, что должен выполниться JS код, пробовал отправлять запрос через SPLASH `

```
script = """
        function main(splash,args)
            splash:autoload("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js")
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            assert(splash:wait(0.5))
            assert(splash:jsfunc('document.form_ok.submit()'))
            assert(splash:wait(1))
            return {html = splash:html(),}
          end
        """
SplashFormRequest(url='http://catalogue.ufi.it/grid_1/grid_1.php', endpoint='execute', formdata=fd, args={'lua_source': script,'http_method':'POST','url': 'http://catalogue.ufi.it/grid_1/grid_1.php','wait': 1})
```

Но ответ приходит, что неправильный запрос к БД, плиз хелп...
Мой код:

```
import scrapy
import os
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import sqlite3

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ufi" 

    def start_requests(self):
        
        urls = [
            'http://catalogue.ufi.it/menu/menu.php?lingua=en',
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        iframe_src = response.xpath('//iframe/@src').extract_first()
        chunk_src = iframe_src.split('?')
        break_src = chunk_src[1].split('&')
        keys = []
        value = []
        for it in break_src:
            temp = it.split("=")
            keys.append(temp[0])
            value.append(temp[1])
        res_data = dict(zip(keys,value))
        
        r = scrapy.FormRequest(url='http://catalogue.ufi.it/grid_1/grid_1.php', callback=self.parse_fr, formdata = res_data)
        r.meta['sess'] = res_data['script_case_session']
        yield r

    def parse_fr(self, response):

        script = """
        function main(splash,args)
            splash:autoload("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js")
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            assert(splash:wait(0.5))
            assert(splash:jsfunc('document.form_ok.submit()'))
            assert(splash:wait(1))
            return {html = splash:html(),}
          end
        """
fd = {'script_case_init':'1','script_case_session':response.meta['sess'],'nmgp_opcao':'busca','catalogo_cond':'eq','catalogo':'2##@@UFI MOTOR CARS','marcamod_cond':'eq','marcamod':'1473##@@TATA cars','modello_idmodello_cond':'eq','modello_idmodello':'11079##@@Vista','versione_idversione_cond':'eq','versione_idversione':'','NM_operador':'and','nmgp_tab_label':'catalogo?#?Catalogue?@?marcamod?#?Brand?@?modello_idmodello?#?Model?@?versione_idversione?#?Version?@?','bprocessa':'pesq','form_condicao':'3'}

SplashFormRequest(url='http://catalogue.ufi.it/grid_1/grid_1.php', endpoint='execute', formdata=fd, args={'lua_source': script,'http_method':'POST','url': 'http://catalogue.ufi.it/grid_1/grid_1.php','wait': 1})
```

Comment: Смотрели вариант с selenium?

Comment: Да, смотрел, но еще не пробовал, как он отработает на несколько тысяч запросов?

Comment: Нужно замерять, но точно медленнее, чем напрямую запросы слать. Кст, а добавьте в вопрос ваш код, или у вас только код с `SplashFormRequest` и есть?

Comment: добавил код в вопрос, единственное показал просто пример словаря туда данные о категории, бренде и моделе подаются из БД в цикле